# Make "Or" clause using objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I am trying to create a query in Objectify with "OR" clause, but i dont found in any place how to do it.
Even reading the [user's guide](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts?tm=6) of Objectify v5, i don't found anything.
I found only this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261136/make-or-clause-using-objectify), but it not apply to me.

In sql the clause would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM bulletin WHERE visibility = 'public' OR ownerId = :userId
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the low-level API `Query.CompositeFilter` object directly, which supports some level of AND and OR composition:

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.Filter filter = // see docs
ofy().load().type(Thing.class).filter(filter);
```

Here are some examples of how to make a composite filter:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query.CompositeFilter

Comment: Is this an Objectify 5+ feature?

Answer (score 2):

The problem that Google Datastore doesn't support `OR` filters at all (only multiply values of same field, `IN`).

But you can make two separate queries and join results into one.

Comment: thanks, but this was my current solution and i was trying to avoid this.